# Flexbox help needed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to space my navigation items in my header evenly for desktop display using flexbox, `justify content: space-around`.

However it seems as though having `.header` also set to flex is interfering, as I am able to implement space-around when I comment out `.header` as display flex.

Tried everything I can think of, so now I come to the experts!
Any ideas greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```css
.header {
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="h1">made tight</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-bars is-hidden-tablet" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <!--non-mobile nav-->
    <ul class="header-ul is-hidden-mobile">
      <li href='#'>Home</li>
      <li href='#'>Studio</li>
      <li href='#'>Services</li>
      <li href='#'>Careers</li>
      <li class='contact-li' href='#'>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Comment: I think the problem is you have 2 sets of flex so your items cannot be spaced evenly, you can make the ul take up the rest of the space and then space the li evenly: https://jsfiddle.net/2gqb6f2t/ (not sure if this is what you are after)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin-left` to `ul.header-ul.is-hidden-mobile li`

```css
.header {
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
ul.header-ul.is-hidden-mobile li {
margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="h1">made tight</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-bars is-hidden-tablet" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <!--non-mobile nav-->
    <ul class="header-ul is-hidden-mobile">
      <li href='#'>Home</li>
      <li href='#'>Studio</li>
      <li href='#'>Services</li>
      <li href='#'>Careers</li>
      <li class='contact-li' href='#'>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Comment: All these suggestions are really helpful. Seems to work a treat, thanks Sagar

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-grow: 1` to make the nav fill the remaining space.

```css
.header {
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="h1">made tight</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-bars is-hidden-tablet" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <!--non-mobile nav-->
    <ul class="header-ul is-hidden-mobile">
      <li href='#'>Home</li>
      <li href='#'>Studio</li>
      <li href='#'>Services</li>
      <li href='#'>Careers</li>
      <li class='contact-li' href='#'>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks very much Jesse